# How to use SVG with multiple paths in Google Maps marker JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I know how to use the SVG path in the icon object that displays in Google Map but how can I add an SVG with multiple paths?

Lets take this SVG with multiple paths:

```
    svg = '<svg height="35" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 411.02 361.23">'
        +'<path d="M23.36,342.13a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-2.78-1.64l-.25-.46-.27-.44a3.37,3.37,0,0,1,.14-2.91L202,21.48a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,3.54-2.38A4.08,4.08,0,0,1,208.65,21l182,315a4,4,0,0,1,.31,3.54l-.27.43-.23.44a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-2.8,1.66Z" style="fill:#fff"/>'
        +'<path d="M344.78,313.39l-139.26-241L66.27,313.39ZM23.36,342.13a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-2.78-1.64l-.25-.46-.27-.44a3.37,3.37,0,0,1,.14-2.91L202,21.48a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,3.54-2.38A4.08,4.08,0,0,1,208.65,21l182,315a4,4,0,0,1,.31,3.54l-.27.43-.23.44a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-2.8,1.66Z" style="fill:#666"/>'
        +'<path d="M166,216.36l-8.44-6.14a13.08,13.08,0,0,1-.93,1.4c-2.22,2.57-5.25,2.94-7.68,1a5.56,5.56,0,0,1-.83-8.05c4.06-5.19,8.19-10.32,12.3-15.47,1.94-2.44,4-4.82,5.81-7.35a8.52,8.52,0,0,1,7.33-3.64c10.22,0,20.44-.12,30.65,0,8.81.13,16,7.72,16,16.56q0,26.06,0,52.1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,1.4,2.9c9.21,6.61,18.35,13.29,27.51,20,.23.17.47.3.81.52l3.31-4.8c1.51-2.18,2.91-2.44,5-.91L275,276.62c.3.23.62.43,1.06.72a42.66,42.66,0,0,0,3.43-4.58,5.07,5.07,0,0,0,.27-3.08c-.55-3.42,1-5.16,3.85-7.05,5.31-3.49,10.72-5.25,17.08-4.62a10.23,10.23,0,0,1,5.77,2c4,3.13,8.17,6,12.25,9.06a5,5,0,0,1,1.36,1.42q12.24,21.15,24.42,42.32a4.9,4.9,0,0,1,.26.61h-112a67.9,67.9,0,0,0,5-7.07c2.05-3.81,4.93-5.45,9.17-4.6,2.86.57,4.68-.63,6.06-3.1a53.06,53.06,0,0,1,3.49-4.89l-8-5.6c-1.69-1.18-3.4-2.34-5.07-3.56s-2-2.82-.73-4.59,2.36-3.23,3.61-4.93L218,254.15c-.41.19-.85.41-1.3.59-3.74,1.53-7.59-.79-7.56-4.83a4.58,4.58,0,0,0-2.41-4.27c-4.57-3.1-9-6.37-13.52-9.58a3.9,3.9,0,0,0-1.51-.7c1.26,1.94,2.5,3.9,3.78,5.83,4.41,6.71,8.81,13.43,13.28,20.11a11.32,11.32,0,0,1,2,6.45c0,12.23,0,24.46,0,36.69,0,4.35-2.36,7.64-5.92,8.55a8.11,8.11,0,0,1-9.77-7,22.43,22.43,0,0,1-.16-2.84c0-10,0-20,0-30a5.57,5.57,0,0,0-.83-2.77c-5-7.83-10.16-15.62-15.25-23.42-.27-.41-.57-.81-1-1.48-.05.75-.1,1.21-.1,1.67,0,7.43,0,14.85,0,22.28a11.47,11.47,0,0,1-1.59,6.05q-9.69,16.51-19.34,33.07a8.16,8.16,0,0,1-8.2,4.43,7.56,7.56,0,0,1-6.58-5.22c-1-2.6-.39-5,1-7.35q8.12-14,16.14-28a6.15,6.15,0,0,0,.79-3c.06-13.13.11-26.25,0-39.37a15.88,15.88,0,0,1,3.33-9.93C164.07,218.93,165,217.69,166,216.36Zm43-5c-5,6.36-9.62,12.33-14.33,18.35L209,240Zm-47.43-5.92,8.25,6L185.2,191.9a2.85,2.85,0,0,0-.6-.25c-3.79-.12-7.58-.26-11.37-.31a1.78,1.78,0,0,0-1.18.73C168.59,196.45,165.17,200.86,161.57,205.47Z"/>'
        +'<path d="M205.43,161.57a15.86,15.86,0,0,1,15.81-15.9c8.52,0,15.72,7.43,15.69,16.12A16.11,16.11,0,0,1,221,177.51,15.83,15.83,0,0,1,205.43,161.57Z"/></svg>';
```

...and add it here:

```
        var icon = {
            path: svg,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: .6,
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            strokeWeight: 0,
            scale: 1
        }

        var domMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: latitude, lng:longitude},
            map: hMap,
            draggable: false,
            icon: svg
        });
```

Having only one path works perfectly fine:

```
        var icon = {
            path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: .6,
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            strokeWeight: 0,
            scale: 1
        }
```

Having multiple paths combining like this it still doesnt work:

```
        var icon = {
            path: "M23.36,342.13a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-2.78-1.64l-.25-.46-.27-.44a3.37,3.37,0,0,1,.14-2.91L202,21.48a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,3.54-2.38A4.08,4.08,0,0,1,208.65,21l182,315a4,4,0,0,1,.31,3.54l-.27.43-.23.44a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-2.8,1.66Z"
            +" M344.78,313.39l-139.26-241L66.27,313.39ZM23.36,342.13a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-2.78-1.64l-.25-.46-.27-.44a3.37,3.37,0,0,1,.14-2.91L202,21.48a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,3.54-2.38A4.08,4.08,0,0,1,208.65,21l182,315a4,4,0,0,1,.31,3.54l-.27.43-.23.44a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-2.8,1.66Z"
            +" M166,216.36l-8.44-6.14a13.08,13.08,0,0,1-.93,1.4c-2.22,2.57-5.25,2.94-7.68,1a5.56,5.56,0,0,1-.83-8.05c4.06-5.19,8.19-10.32,12.3-15.47,1.94-2.44,4-4.82,5.81-7.35a8.52,8.52,0,0,1,7.33-3.64c10.22,0,20.44-.12,30.65,0,8.81.13,16,7.72,16,16.56q0,26.06,0,52.1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,1.4,2.9c9.21,6.61,18.35,13.29,27.51,20,.23.17.47.3.81.52l3.31-4.8c1.51-2.18,2.91-2.44,5-.91L275,276.62c.3.23.62.43,1.06.72a42.66,42.66,0,0,0,3.43-4.58,5.07,5.07,0,0,0,.27-3.08c-.55-3.42,1-5.16,3.85-7.05,5.31-3.49,10.72-5.25,17.08-4.62a10.23,10.23,0,0,1,5.77,2c4,3.13,8.17,6,12.25,9.06a5,5,0,0,1,1.36,1.42q12.24,21.15,24.42,42.32a4.9,4.9,0,0,1,.26.61h-112a67.9,67.9,0,0,0,5-7.07c2.05-3.81,4.93-5.45,9.17-4.6,2.86.57,4.68-.63,6.06-3.1a53.06,53.06,0,0,1,3.49-4.89l-8-5.6c-1.69-1.18-3.4-2.34-5.07-3.56s-2-2.82-.73-4.59,2.36-3.23,3.61-4.93L218,254.15c-.41.19-.85.41-1.3.59-3.74,1.53-7.59-.79-7.56-4.83a4.58,4.58,0,0,0-2.41-4.27c-4.57-3.1-9-6.37-13.52-9.58a3.9,3.9,0,0,0-1.51-.7c1.26,1.94,2.5,3.9,3.78,5.83,4.41,6.71,8.81,13.43,13.28,20.11a11.32,11.32,0,0,1,2,6.45c0,12.23,0,24.46,0,36.69,0,4.35-2.36,7.64-5.92,8.55a8.11,8.11,0,0,1-9.77-7,22.43,22.43,0,0,1-.16-2.84c0-10,0-20,0-30a5.57,5.57,0,0,0-.83-2.77c-5-7.83-10.16-15.62-15.25-23.42-.27-.41-.57-.81-1-1.48-.05.75-.1,1.21-.1,1.67,0,7.43,0,14.85,0,22.28a11.47,11.47,0,0,1-1.59,6.05q-9.69,16.51-19.34,33.07a8.16,8.16,0,0,1-8.2,4.43,7.56,7.56,0,0,1-6.58-5.22c-1-2.6-.39-5,1-7.35q8.12-14,16.14-28a6.15,6.15,0,0,0,.79-3c.06-13.13.11-26.25,0-39.37a15.88,15.88,0,0,1,3.33-9.93C164.07,218.93,165,217.69,166,216.36Zm43-5c-5,6.36-9.62,12.33-14.33,18.35L209,240Zm-47.43-5.92,8.25,6L185.2,191.9a2.85,2.85,0,0,0-.6-.25c-3.79-.12-7.58-.26-11.37-.31a1.78,1.78,0,0,0-1.18.73C168.59,196.45,165.17,200.86,161.57,205.47Z"
            +" M205.43,161.57a15.86,15.86,0,0,1,15.81-15.9c8.52,0,15.72,7.43,15.69,16.12A16.11,16.11,0,0,1,221,177.51,15.83,15.83,0,0,1,205.43,161.57Z",
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: .6,
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            strokeWeight: 0,
            scale: 1
        };
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Rojo its impossible to reproduce this. How would you reproduce a google maps JavaScript example?

Comment: Create a minimal example starting with https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom .

Comment: It is certainly possible to reproduce it.  See the [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in my answer.  I will admit that knowing the Google test key that work on SO does require some experience, but  Google provides working keys for there sample fiddles, and a code snippet with everything but the key would have been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps [SVG Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) only support a single path.  You can load the complete svg file as an icon if it is publicly available on the internet.

Related questions:

- [rotate svg marker with multiple paths using google maps javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403305/rotate-svg-marker-with-multiple-paths-using-google-maps-javascript/46416240?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C127.4990#46416240)
- [Rotate marker on google maps with svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809915/rotate-marker-on-google-maps-with-svg)
- [Creating a multi color svg icon for google map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991564/creating-a-multi-color-svg-icon-for-google-map-marker)

Or, instead of loading it as a file, you can add it as a [`data url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```
icon: {
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
  url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg)
},
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/75bcv9fa/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var svg = '<svg height="35" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 411.02 361.23">' +
  '<path d="M23.36,342.13a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-2.78-1.64l-.25-.46-.27-.44a3.37,3.37,0,0,1,.14-2.91L202,21.48a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,3.54-2.38A4.08,4.08,0,0,1,208.65,21l182,315a4,4,0,0,1,.31,3.54l-.27.43-.23.44a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-2.8,1.66Z" style="fill:#fff"/>' +
  '<path d="M344.78,313.39l-139.26-241L66.27,313.39ZM23.36,342.13a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-2.78-1.64l-.25-.46-.27-.44a3.37,3.37,0,0,1,.14-2.91L202,21.48a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,3.54-2.38A4.08,4.08,0,0,1,208.65,21l182,315a4,4,0,0,1,.31,3.54l-.27.43-.23.44a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-2.8,1.66Z" style="fill:#666"/>' +
  '<path d="M166,216.36l-8.44-6.14a13.08,13.08,0,0,1-.93,1.4c-2.22,2.57-5.25,2.94-7.68,1a5.56,5.56,0,0,1-.83-8.05c4.06-5.19,8.19-10.32,12.3-15.47,1.94-2.44,4-4.82,5.81-7.35a8.52,8.52,0,0,1,7.33-3.64c10.22,0,20.44-.12,30.65,0,8.81.13,16,7.72,16,16.56q0,26.06,0,52.1a3.1,3.1,0,0,0,1.4,2.9c9.21,6.61,18.35,13.29,27.51,20,.23.17.47.3.81.52l3.31-4.8c1.51-2.18,2.91-2.44,5-.91L275,276.62c.3.23.62.43,1.06.72a42.66,42.66,0,0,0,3.43-4.58,5.07,5.07,0,0,0,.27-3.08c-.55-3.42,1-5.16,3.85-7.05,5.31-3.49,10.72-5.25,17.08-4.62a10.23,10.23,0,0,1,5.77,2c4,3.13,8.17,6,12.25,9.06a5,5,0,0,1,1.36,1.42q12.24,21.15,24.42,42.32a4.9,4.9,0,0,1,.26.61h-112a67.9,67.9,0,0,0,5-7.07c2.05-3.81,4.93-5.45,9.17-4.6,2.86.57,4.68-.63,6.06-3.1a53.06,53.06,0,0,1,3.49-4.89l-8-5.6c-1.69-1.18-3.4-2.34-5.07-3.56s-2-2.82-.73-4.59,2.36-3.23,3.61-4.93L218,254.15c-.41.19-.85.41-1.3.59-3.74,1.53-7.59-.79-7.56-4.83a4.58,4.58,0,0,0-2.41-4.27c-4.57-3.1-9-6.37-13.52-9.58a3.9,3.9,0,0,0-1.51-.7c1.26,1.94,2.5,3.9,3.78,5.83,4.41,6.71,8.81,13.43,13.28,20.11a11.32,11.32,0,0,1,2,6.45c0,12.23,0,24.46,0,36.69,0,4.35-2.36,7.64-5.92,8.55a8.11,8.11,0,0,1-9.77-7,22.43,22.43,0,0,1-.16-2.84c0-10,0-20,0-30a5.57,5.57,0,0,0-.83-2.77c-5-7.83-10.16-15.62-15.25-23.42-.27-.41-.57-.81-1-1.48-.05.75-.1,1.21-.1,1.67,0,7.43,0,14.85,0,22.28a11.47,11.47,0,0,1-1.59,6.05q-9.69,16.51-19.34,33.07a8.16,8.16,0,0,1-8.2,4.43,7.56,7.56,0,0,1-6.58-5.22c-1-2.6-.39-5,1-7.35q8.12-14,16.14-28a6.15,6.15,0,0,0,.79-3c.06-13.13.11-26.25,0-39.37a15.88,15.88,0,0,1,3.33-9.93C164.07,218.93,165,217.69,166,216.36Zm43-5c-5,6.36-9.62,12.33-14.33,18.35L209,240Zm-47.43-5.92,8.25,6L185.2,191.9a2.85,2.85,0,0,0-.6-.25c-3.79-.12-7.58-.26-11.37-.31a1.78,1.78,0,0,0-1.18.73C168.59,196.45,165.17,200.86,161.57,205.47Z"/>' +
  '<path d="M205.43,161.57a15.86,15.86,0,0,1,15.81-15.9c8.52,0,15.72,7.43,15.69,16.12A16.11,16.11,0,0,1,221,177.51,15.83,15.83,0,0,1,205.43,161.57Z"/></svg>';

function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
  });
  new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: {
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg)
    },
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Hello World!",
    draggable: true,
    zIndex: 10
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Markers</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, eventhough you are saying that Google Maps support only single path SVGs, you still made it work with multiple paths! Can you give an explanation?

Comment: The native [SVG Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) (what you were trying to use) only supports a single path.  But that doesn't prevent you from loading a multipath svg as a "file" (or using a data url to do the same).